# Python Slack API direct message by slackbot to user issue

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

I made a slackbot that does three things: send a pi's IP to a general channel, check if the IP is the same as last time and send the IP as a DM.
The 2 first ones work, but the DM doesn't.

I was trying to find the error, but at some point *my `prints` just wouldn't print* anymore.. I'm not sure as to why. (More specifically from when I added `print("im call success")`)

Here is the part of my code that I have a problem with:

```
                user_slack_id = 'axelle'
                im_call = slack_client.api_call("im.list")

                if im_call.get('ok'):
                    print("im call success")
                    for im in im_call.get('ims'):
                        if im.get('user') == user_slack_id:
                            im_channel = im.get('id')
                            send_msg(channel[im_channel], "Test")
```

`send_msg` works, since I use it for my general channel post. It's basically just a `slack_client api call` to post a message.

Simply nothing is happening on my Slack channel in terms of DM's.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I've had a lot of success working with https://github.com/lins05/slackbot out of the box with minimal configuration effort, which is from the pypi index: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slackbot

Comment: It seems a bit complicated for a beginner like me but I'll take a look thank you :) can probably learn alot from it.